# Dark Mode IOS overrideUserInterfaceStyle is not applied

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

```
            overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

I have several viewControllers using this code but darkMode is not applied with this code.
Is being used in viewDidLoad

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to this in a UIViewController, you would just do this.

```
 overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

Again, we assign either a light a dark value (usually within `viewDidLoad()`).

## Window

If we need to access the current window, we could do so as follows:

```
for window in UIApplicationl.shared.windows {
    window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
}
```

(This is not a recommended approach and you would be hard-pressed to find any real reason to want to do this...)